# Refresh scope not updating properties but refreshing the bean itself

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

i am trying to refresh a refresh scope bean using actuator.The class that needs to be refreshed:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "push-sync")
@RefreshScope
public class PushSyncProperties {

    private boolean available = true;
    private int maxSyncThreads = 5;
    private int maxRequestsPerSecond = 5;
    private int maxRetries = 10;
    private long initialRetryDelay = 7 * 1000L;
    private long maxRetryDelay = 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
    private int retryBackOffMultiplier = 3;
    private long dbCheckInterval = 10 * 1000L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void refresh()
    {
        log.info("Application Refreshed!");
        log.info(String.valueOf(maxSyncThreads));
    }
```

part of the pom

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the main class

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({PushSyncProperties.class})
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("file:${push.sync.config}")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        String pushSyncConfigPath = SystemProperties.get("push.sync.config");
        return application.sources(Application.class)
                .properties(
                        "spring.config.location:classpath:/application.yml, " + pushSyncConfigPath
                );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

however, whenever changing a property from that specific file that maps my property class, the postConstruct function is called, but the value is never updated. Any idea why?

Comment: did you ever get this to work? have been asked to make reloadable configs happen with Springboot and have tried everything seemingly